# Android Device Monitor is not being shown properly

Tags: android, device, monitor, android-device-monitor

in Android device monitor, the folder names and file names are not shown completely and I have trouble finding my intended files , as shown in the picture , is there any one who can help me?[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYKKY.png)

Comment: Can't you just resize the columns by clicking and dragging on the lines between the column headers?

Answer (score 1):

use "Device File Explorer" of android studio.Here you can see.[image: i have attached screenShot]

Answer (score 0):

Android Device Monitor is deprecated now, try to use other tools if it's possible (more info here: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor)